# How to solve: "JSON parse error - Extra data" DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

When I try to send data in DRF's api_view I recieve this error.
[I can create only blank post and can't type any of key-value data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWKFI.png)

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_post(request):
    serializer = PostSerializer(data={**request.data, "author": request.user.id})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    text = models.TextField("Текст поста", blank=True, default="")
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, to_field='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
    updated = models.DateTimeField("Дата обновления", auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Дата публикации", auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField("Имаге", blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, verbose_name="Классы", blank=True, related_name='profile_liked')
```

**serializer.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Создаёт и возвращает экземпляр Post.
        """
        return Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

I tried all I could except use ajax (but I want to use it in future).

Comment: Your content is not a valid json, should be something like `{"text": "aaa"}`

Comment: I also agree with @GonzaloOdiard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I tried to write data with {} but got an Expected value error. While solving the problem, I changed the code a lot and did not check this option again. Thank to [Gonzalo Odiard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3969110/gonzalo-odiard)!

**So right way to type is:**

```
{"key":"value"}
```

**Not:**

```
"key":"value"
```